# Форматирование числа типа double

Tags: java

Нужно округлить число PI чтоб оно было  `3,141592653`

Я использовал форматирование и класc  DecimalFormat:

```
public class UseDicimalVar{

   public static void controlFormat(String patern, double value){
       DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat(patern);
       String finishLook = myFormat.format(value);
       System.out.printf("before formater %.12f --> after %s %n"  , value , finishLook);
   }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        controlFormat("#.#########", Math.PI);
    }
}
```

но вместо 3,141592653  выводит 3,14159265***4***
Аналогично и с `System.out.printf("%.9f",Math.PI);`

**Вопрос:** *как сделать так ,чтоб не округляло, а просто было определённое количиство символов после запятой?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Math.PI);
bd = bd.setScale(9, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
double r = bd.doubleValue();

System.out.println(r);
```

Comment: Не подходит....Оно выдает число полностю без сокращения !!!!!

Comment: @Vitaliy Исправил. В это коде число округляется до 9 знака в меньшую сторону (3.141592653589793 -> 3.141592653).

Comment: изменил, но без результатно :( выводит  3.141592653589793

Comment: @Vitaliy посмотрите результат выполнения тут http://goo.gl/oT338w

Comment: @pavelip...спасибо большое!!! Не увидел ошибку ..